# Request.PathInfo issues and XSS attacks

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, xss, penetration-testing

I have a couple of websites running on .NET 3.5 still due to an API restriction. We will eventually move these sites to the latest .NET version this year. One of the penetration tests indicated a possible XSS vulnerability. The URL in question is:

> Location: http://www.foobar.com/basket.aspx/scripts/searchresults.aspx
>
> Method: GET
>
> Vulnerable Parameter: name of an arbitrarily supplied URL parameter

Basically, anything after `basket.aspx` like `scripts/searchresults.aspx` will cause the issue. From what I can determine, `Request.PathInfo` will try to find the path and eventually reach `searchresults.aspx` (if the .aspx page exists) but all my CSS and scripts can't be found due to relative paths. The page essentially breaks. It's unclear how this could cause an XSS vulnerability. Nevertheless, it does break the page.

My question: Is `Request.PathInfo` needed? In my preliminary tests, if I check `Request.PathInfo`, I can determine that it may be a bad URL request:

```
FooBar.Global pageObj = obj;

if (obj.Request.PathInfo.Length > 0)
{
   Response.Redirect("~/sitemap.aspx", true); // bad url send to site map
}
```

Comment: do you have ValidateRequest="false" in the page?

Comment: and this in web.config?  <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />

Comment: ValidateRequest is set to false on the page and no to httpRuntime in the web config. Currently, I do not have a httpRuntime entry

Comment: ValidateRequest="true" should take care of it then.  But sometimes people have a valid reason to set it to false (not normally tho).

Comment: Yes,  - but can you tell me if there are any side affects to clearing Request.PathInfo? I dont used it, and from my testing, it will fix .net from trying to recursively find the page.

Comment: I can't say for sure because I haven't worked with 3.5 for a long time now, but I don't see anything inherently wrong with your approach.  It is definitely an improvement over your current method.  I do similar things with checking authentication all the time (ie, something is not like it should be, redirect).

Comment: I think the acunetix trial version will show you xss vulnerabilities.  https://www.acunetix.com/vulnerability-scanner/download/

Comment: @PhillyNJ: Are you using WebForms? How are you including your CSS and scripts on the page?

Comment: Yes. The CSS and scripts are called in the master page.

Comment: @PhillyNJ: Can you please show the code or markup that the master page uses to include the CSS and scripts?

Comment: Like so: `<link href="../App_Themes/MySite/Master.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />` - scripts are done similarly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is [Request.PathInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.pathinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) needed?

PathInfo isn't required by ASP.NET WebForms. [It can be helpful for search engine optimization](https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/tip-trick-url-rewriting-with-asp-net), but if you don't use it, go ahead and disable it. You can add your code snippet, or you can install [UrlScan](https://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/working-with-urlscan/urlscan-3-reference) and set the AllowDotInPath option to 0.

> How could this cause an XSS vulnerability?

Your page may be vulnerable to a [Relative Path Overwrite (RPO)](https://www.google.com/search?q=Relative%20Path%20Overwrite) attack if all these criteria are met:

1. An attacker can inject content (for example, a blog comment) somewhere into the page.
2. Your page references a CSS stylesheet via a relative path.
3. PathInfo is enabled.

By appending PathInfo to the URL, an attacker can cause your page to load *itself* as the stylesheet because ASP.NET resolves Page.aspx/Master.css to just Page.aspx, not to Master.css. Due to the lax (by design) parsing rules for CSS, the attacker's content may be interpreted as valid CSS, which is *especially* bad for old versions of Internet Explorer that allow JavaScript in CSS. Even in modern browsers, a malicious stylesheet can inject content that misleads other users.

> I want to use PathInfo. How can I mitigate this vulnerability?

Use absolute paths to reference all CSS stylesheets. For example, you can call the [ResolveUrl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.resolveurl(v=vs.110).aspx) method with an app-relative path (a virtual path starting with `~/`):

```
<link href='<%= this.ResolveUrl("~/App_Themes/MySite/Master.css") %>' rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

**Caution:** Don't use the [ResolveClientUrl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.resolveclienturl(v=vs.110).aspx) method because it returns a relative path.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like the pentester noticed that if they supplied a URL like:

http://www.foobar.com/basket.aspx/scripts/searchresults.aspx?foo=bar

That the resulting page would have `foo=bar` somewhere in there. This would be vulnerable to XSS unless proper escaping was used, since someone could submit JavaScript as part of that value.