# Validating URLs - Why does this not throw a 404?

Tags: asp.net

I'm seeing a problem with one of our company's websites, and I can't for the life of me find a solution (here or otherwise).

Essentially, the issue is that anything can be appended to a URL after a .aspx, provided you add a / and everything before the slash is valid.

As an example: say you have a page https://somesite.com/default.aspx
We can then add a / and any string: https://somesite.com/default.aspx/somestring/someotherstring
and it just treats the page as if it's the original URL.

Why would this not throw a 404 at the very least? Does it think this is a web method, even though it doesn't exist?

Any idea on how to catch/validate this?

The site is targeting .net 4.5.2 and is in the MVP pattern.

Comment: By MVP pattern, do you mean you're using MVP on top of WebForm?

Comment: Correct, yes. It's an older site, slated for a rewrite this year - but we're trying to address some issue found during penetration testing at the moment.

Comment: You're seeing a problem - what exactly is the problem that's causing you to seek why this works the way it does? It seems more of a curiosity of how it was implemented rather than a problem.

Comment: Is the someotherstring in question contains dot (".")? If so, this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42211237/request-pathinfo-issues-and-xss-attacks, if any random string count even if it doesn't contain space, can you include the complete issue from the pentester?

Comment: _Is the someotherstring in question contains dot (".")?_

It can, but doesn't need to. Thanks for that link, I hadn't found it in my searches. Looks like they solved their CSS loading problem, but the root cause was not. I was essentially looking to figure out why it resolves the URL - and how to catch/validate/block appending of random strings to the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your comment state the `someotherstring` doesn't have to contain dot, this will need a hacky approach. FWIW, the default WebForm project (targeting 4.5.1 and 4.8) I tried creating on VS 2019 already return 404 for any request where the `someotherstring` *or* `somestring` contains dot, while allowing other requests that don't contain dot. Meanwhile, the default MVC project targeting .NET Core 3.1 have stricter rules, but *some* variation of somestring and someotherstring are still somewhat possible (they're after all, valid for some scenarios).

On WebForm, each Page can access [Page.AppRelativeVirtualPath](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.templatecontrol.apprelativevirtualpath) which will contain the actual path being executed and [Request.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httprequest.apprelativecurrentexecutionfilepath) which will contain the path being requested. By comparing them, you can then either redirect or just throw HTTPException.

Here's a very rough starting point, you can put them on MasterPage and be on your way if it doesn't break your app, or tweak them to allow the valid scenarios.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.AppRelativeVirtualPath.Replace(".aspx","").
        Equals(Request.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath.Replace(".aspx",""),
        StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
    {

        throw new HttpException(404, "Page doesn't exist");
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks - I was thinking something similarly hacky in global.asax on PreRequest. I still find it odd that any of this is allowed in the first place =)

Comment: All of these was done long before XSS was even a thing. I guess the original intent was "don't break the existing stuff"